# Why is there at least a $50$% chance that greatest common divisor $(n,x-y)$ is a factor of $n$ not equal to $0$, $1$, or $n$?

Tags: probability, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given integers $x$, $y$, and $n$ such that $x^2\equiv y^2 ($mod$ n)$, there is at least a $50$% chance that greatest common divisor $(n,x-y)$ is a factor of $n$ not equal to $1$, $0$, or $n$.  Why is it at least $50$%?

I think it is because if $x\not\equiv±y($mod$ n)$, then gcd$(n,x-y)$ is a factor of $n$ not equal to $1$, $0$, or $n$, but if $x\equiv±y($mod$ n)$, then gcd$(n,x-y)$ must equal $n$, $1$ or $0$.

My Guess:
Let’s say we find an $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2 ≡ y^2($mod$ n)$.

Then $(x – y)(x + y) = 0 ($mod$ n)$

First, if either $x$ or $y$ is $0$, then gcd$(n, x - y) = 0$

If $x ≡ y($mod$ $n)$, then gcd$(n, x - y) = 0$ or $n$.

If $x ≡ -y($mod$ $n)$, then gcd$(n, x - y) = 1$ or $n$

If $x ≡ y(mod$ $n)$, then gcd$(n, x + y) = 1$ or $n$

If $x ≡ -y(mod$ $n)$, then gcd$(n, x + y) = 0$ or $n$

But if $x$ is not congruent to $± y($mod $n)$, then gcd$(n, x + y)$ does not equal $0$, $1$, or $n$.

So when $x^2 ≡ y^2(mod$ $n)$, there is at least a $50$% chance that gcd$(n, x + y)$ is a non-trivial factor of $n$ (a factor not equal $0$, $1$, or $n$).

Is this correct?

Comment: So does that means there are at least 2 things it could be which are not $n$ or $1$ right? Why 2?

Comment: That does not make sense. If $n$ is a prime then it does not even have any other divisors. I would forget about the rephrasing and try to interpret the original question in terms of some probability distribution.

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ could be useful here to consider as if $(x^2-y^2) \mid n$ then the difference of squares factoring would produce a couple of factors.

Comment: I used that fact in my guess of an answer in the second part of the question.  Is my guess, which uses that fact, incorrect?

Comment: It is not clear which of the three elements $x,$ $y$ and $n$ are random, and if they are random, what distribution they follow. For instance, if $n$ is fixed and given as a prime, and $x$ and $y$ are uniformly distributed (but conditional on their squares being congruent) then it is impossible for the gcd to be different from 1 and $n.$ That means 0% chance by any interpretation of probability.

Answer (score 1):

The given statement is correct for numbers $n$ with at least two distinct odd prime factors. (to be more precise, if there is no primitive root modulo $n$ , but the case of $n$ odd and $n$ has two distinct prime factors is the most important in practice)

Suppose, $n$ is divisible by the odd distinct primes $p$ and $q$ and $x^2\equiv y^2\ ($mod $n$).

If $gcd(x,y)\ne1$, then there exists a prime $r$ such that  $r|x$ and $r|y$.
In such a case case, $r$ also divides $x-y$ and therefore $x^2-y^2$. Hence $r|gcd(n,x-y)$.

If $x\equiv y\ ($mod $n\ )$, then $gcd(x-y,n)=$$n$. Because $n > 2r$,
this occurs with probability at most $\frac{1}{2}$.

If $gcd(x,y)=1$, then we have that $gcd(n,y)=1$. If it didn't, there would be a prime $r$ dividing $n$ and $y$, so we would have that $x^2\equiv 0\ ($mod $r)$, implying $x\equiv 0\ ($mod $r )$, which is a contradiction to $gcd(x,y)=1$.

Hence, $x^2\equiv y^2\ (\ mod\ n)$ can be transformed into $z^2\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$.

The solution of the system $p\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$ $q\equiv -1\ (\ mod\ n)$ and the solution of the system $p\equiv-1\ (\ mod\ n)$ $q\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$ are two non-trivial solutions. So, the case $gcd(x,y)=1$ gives a chance of at least $\frac{1}{2}$ to find a factor because the equation $z^2\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ n)$ has at least $4$ solutions, two of which are trivial.